# How to close this loop to avoid stopiteration error

Tags: python, file, file-io

I'm trying to use the "next()" method in the context manager to read an input file for a question I'm solving however I run into this stopiteration error.

[Here's the link to the current question I am doing](https://orac2.info/problem/simplerect/)

Here's the code I've written for the file so far, I haven't exactly worked on the calculation bit properly yet, thus, I'm commenting it out, my real problem lies into file reading.

```
#importing modules
import cmath as m

#Declaring Variables and opening files

inputfile = open("bendin.txt", "r")
outputfile = open("bendout.txt", "w")

#reading the inputfile

with inputfile:
    R1 = next(inputfile).split()
    R1x1BL = int(R1[0])
    R1y1BL = int(R1[1])
    R1x2TR = int(R1[2])
    R1y2TR = int(R1[3])
    
    R2 = next(inputfile).split()
    R2x1BL = int(R2[0])
    R2y1BL = int(R2[1])
    R2x2TR = int(R2[2])
    R2y2TR = int(R2[3])
```

At the moment this code runs into the "stopiteration" error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 12, in <module>
    R1 = next(inputfile).split()
StopIteration
```

Here's a sample of the input in a text file:

```
1 2 3 4
4 3 5 2
```

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, StopIteration means that your input has been exhausted, which is the standard mechanics behind the loop-iterations. Could you please provide your input and output

Comment: There is no loop in this code. Please, post [mre] of the actual code that produce `StopIteration`. With the provided 2-line sample. this code will run all right.